# What's the correct permissions to write log from a python CLI?

Tags: linux, logging, command-line-interface

I'm developing python CLI, I want write log file in /var/log/myapp/myapp.log but I don't know What's the correctly permissions that need set to log file in the install, because the CLI can be executed from differents users.

Currently I have this permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 someone someone 137 dic  4 17:00 /var/log/myapp/myapp.log
```

But when another user execute the CLI show this error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/myapp/myapp.log'

I want know what's the correct permissions, user or group to write log in /var/log

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it.  One way would be to put all the users in a group, set the group of that directory to that group, and set the group write permission on /var/log/myapp.  Then all users in the group will be able to write files to that location.

You might need to change the group write permission and group of the file you're creating instead, since all users appear to write to the same file.  Be aware however that they may interfere with each other's logs if you all log to the same file.

Comment: But if I want set the permissions during installation? I don't create or modify new users or groups, I need know how to set permissions to the log file, because the CLI any user can call it.

Comment: I resolved temporally this set permissions 777 in directory /var/log/myapp but I don't know if it is correct.